# Blank space still appear in left and right sides of the ImageView after using adjustViewBounds and scaleType

Tags: java, android

I am a new android programmer.I want to show images with `PullToRefreshListView` ,but I find both the left and right sides of the `ImageView` has blank space.And I have tried the some solution about the "ImageView blank space" including using `adjustViewBounds="true"` and `scaleType`,but it failed.
The following code is my list cell layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/userPortrait"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
         <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeAgo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                 />


    </LinearLayout>


<!-- here is my imageControl -->
    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageUrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

The image comes from server,so I add the image source in code by `imageView.setImageBitmap`.
I also have tried using `imageView.setBackground(drawable)`, actually no blank space appear in the left and right sides,but the height is not incorrect,it does  not depend on  the aspect ratio.

can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried  android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: I have tried the "centerCrop",it display well.But the image has been cropped, it's not the result I want.

Comment: @Maxy have you solved it ?

Answer (score 2):

If the aspect ratio of the `ImageView` after layout is different than the aspect ratio of the image itself, you have to make a choice:

- If you want to fit the entire image into the `ImageView` leaving some space (in your case, left and right), use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.
- If you want to cover the entire `ImageView` and crop the image (in your case, at the top and the bottom), use `android:scaleType="cropCenter"`
- If you don't want to have extra space or cropped sides and want to distort the aspect ratio of the image to match the `ImageView` dimensions exactly, use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Here is how `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` works:  When you have one dimension of the `ImageView` "fixed" (e.g. `match_parent` or `240dp` etc.) and another dimension "flexible" (e.g. `wrap_content`), setting `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` will cause the `ImageView` layout to make the `wrap_content` dimension just the right size to match the aspect ratio of the source image.

Since you have `match_parent` on both dimensions of your `ImageView`, `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` won't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks.I have tried the `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` .According the 'adjustViewBounds' function you mentioned,the image should fill in the width,and the height would be right size to match the aspect ratio.But  I find the height is same as that by setting "fitCenter",so the image actually is distorted.

Comment: If you use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, don't specify a `scaleType` attribute.

Comment: Also specify `wrap_content` for the height of the list item as well.

Comment: Now if I just use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` without 'scaleType',it can't fill in the width,  and  if i just use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` without `adjustViewBounds`,the image would be distroted.

Comment: I have tried many combinations of the several properties ,but it still can't display on the right way.

Comment: Can you post some screen shots?  Label them with the `ImageView` attributes you used for that screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81477/discussion-between-maxy-and-kris-larson).